# How to check WordPress website username and password is correct

Tags: plugin-development, login, rest-api, authentication

On my site i have one form for client to submit their WordPress site details. On that form containing these fields WordPress admin url, username, and password. I want to check their login details are valid before submitting the form. How i do that?

If there any way to do by using WordPress REST API?

If anyone know please help me Thanks !

Comment: without customisation, the REST API doesn't permit to test the password. then if you want to test it, you can send it at `wp-login.php`.

Comment: @mmm how i do that? Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: you can try with [wp_remote_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post)

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679001/register-login-user-with-wordpress-json-api you can test a remote login

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to do something you shouldn't. You could easily build a brute-force attack using your application. What is the usage scenario for your request?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Regarding my site i get the username and password form clients and some of the details are working for me some time user given details are not correct so that i need to email him again to get user name password. That is why i am thinking How i check the user given details are correct on that form. they are giving me username,password and admin url. with these details there is any way to check that user given details are correct.

Comment: i agree with Ciprian, i m surprised why this post request got in the featured list.

Answer (score 3):

Getting user names and passwords is a horrible idea I hope no user will actually agree to, but beyond that your idea to do it from JS is going to fail due to CORS, which means you will have to do it in AJAX to your server, and let your server try to login, which in turn will most likely flag it as a brute force attacker in no time, and all the major security players will just automatically block the requests.

You need to redesign you software to not need user name and password, probably use something like oauth2 instead. If oauth2 is not applicable for your situation.... well, tough luck.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Regarding my site i get the username and password form clients and some of the details are working for me some time user given details are not correct so that i need to email him again to get user name password. That is why i am thinking How i check the user given details are correct on that form. they are giving me username,password and admin url. with these details there is any way to check that user given details are correct.

Comment: it is very insecure to give user name and password anywhere anytime as it is a prime target for phishing attack. Regardless of why you are doing it, no one should be willing to share such information on the web.

Comment: ... if we are talking about wordpress sites, they should just add a user for your email, and let you reset the password for it.

Comment: Yes i am talking about wordpress site. I getting client username and password via website that is why i asking this question here.

Answer (score 1):

First off: there are many reasons why the following code could fail. There is no way to have a system that works everywhere. This is due to various security plugins introducing many different concepts.

Having said that, this code worked for a plain installation as well as one with Wordfence (with not super strict settings) enabled.

---

[`wp_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) is the key function in this function. It allows you to send POST requests to remote hosts - which is exactly what you want if you want to check a login.

```
function WPSE_test_remote_login($url, $username, $password) {
    // remove trailing slash if it exists
    $base = rtrim($url, '/');

    // login url
    $url = $base . '/wp-login.php';

    $args = [
        // the inputs that get POSTed
        'body' => [
            'log' => $username,
            'pwd' => $password,
            'wp-submit' => 'Submit',
            'redirect_to' => $base . '/wp-admin/',
            'testcookie' => 1,
        ],
    ];

    // make the actual request
    $response = wp_remote_post($url, $args);

    // only one cookie? then failed login
    if ( ! is_array($response['headers']['set-cookie'])) {
        return false;
    }

    // if a cookie that contains wordpress_logged_in is set
    // the login was successful
    foreach ($response['headers']['set-cookie'] as $cookie) {
        if (stripos($cookie, 'wordpress_logged_in') !== FALSE) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I tried this in my local environment, you can get the necessary fields that are usually sent if you access the wp-login.php in your browser.

Then I checked the `$result` and compared the difference between correct and wrong password. For a **failed login**, `$response['headers']['set-cookie']` looked like this

> ```
> string(45) "wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/"
> ```

or this

> ```
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(128) "__cfduid=df131...; expires=Sun, 21-Apr-19 12:35:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly"
>   [1]=>
>   string(100) "wfvt_144...=5ad...; expires=Sat, 21-Apr-2018 13:05:00 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; HttpOnly"
>   [2]=>
>   string(74) "wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure"
> }
> ```

However, a **successful login** returned these cookies

> ```
> array(4) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(45) "wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/"
>   [1]=>
>   string(209) "wordpress_852...=test%7C15...; path=/wp-content/plugins; HttpOnly"
>   [2]=>
>   string(199) "wordpress_852...=test%7C15...; path=/wp-admin; HttpOnly"
>   [3]=>
>   string(201) "wordpress_logged_in_852...=test%7C15...; path=/; HttpOnly"
> }
> ```

We see that `wordpress_test_cookie` will always get set. However, `wordpress_logged_in_852...` was only set for successful logins. So we can determine that if this exists, the credentials are correct.

Comment: Well... There are two problems with that solution, I guess. One is that name of cookie can change, so you can't assume it will be always "wordpress_logged_in_852". Second problem is that you not only check if user data is correct, but also log this user in...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż For a software that keeps being developed on, your first argument is always true. Even the name of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook can change. Your second point I agree with and didn't really consider when writing the answer. AFAIK there is no other way to check credentials against a remote site

Comment: of course it is. That’s why it’s always better to use developer API and not such workarounds, I guess :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Regarding my site i get the username and password form clients and some of the details are working for me some time user given details are not correct so that i need to email him again to get user name password. That is why i am thinking How i check the user given details are correct on that form. they are giving me username,password and admin url. with these details there is any way to check that user given details are correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this without any custom API routes. But of course, you can register such route (or use AJAX instead), if you can edit theme or install plugins on that site.

So, let's do this with REST API...

```
function my_register_api_hooks() {
    register_rest_route(
        'my_namespace', '/check-login/',
        array(
            'methods'  => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'my_api_check_login_callback',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_api_hooks' );
    
function my_api_check_login_callback($request){
    $user = wp_authenticate_username_password(null, $request['username'], $request['password']);

    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
        return array('error' => $user, 'user' => false);
    }

    return array('error' => false, 'user' => $user->ID);
}
```

When you'll send a POST request to

```
http://example.com/wp-json/my_namespace/check-login/
```

containing `username` and `password`, you'll get JSON like this:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "user": 1
}
```

where `1` is the ID of user found for given credentials, or

```
{
  "error": "...", <- this will contain error messages
  "user": false
}
```

You have to be aware that this code only checks if user credentials are correct. It will not log user in.

### And what if you have no control over site you want to check?

Then there is no way to register your own routes and there's no way to use REST to check user credentials. But... You can use XMLRPC...

One way will be using this library: [WordPress XML-RPC PHP Client](http://letrunghieu.github.io/wordpress-xmlrpc-client/). It will do the job for you almost all the way or you can use native [WP_HTTP_IXR_Client](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_ixr_client/) class.

You can use `wp.getUsersBlogs` method for checking if given credentials are correct.

Comment: Problem with this is, that OP wants to check a remote/client site - if the site owner has to install a custom plugin first, they could just register them an account

Comment: @kero "On my site i have one form..." I don't see anywhere in the question info saying that the form is sent to some remote site... But... if so, then he should provide some plugin or use xmlrpc authentication. And certainly he should NOT base on wp-login.php... But, I would strongly advice not to put your WP credentials on some remote site - never ;)

Comment: I understood the question that OP may be a plugin developer. And before someone sends their credentials so s/he does support their, s/he wants to check their validity. I agree that this is a bad idea, also since the form is probably sent unencrypted via mail

Comment: @kero and still, OP could do anything with these credentials ;) Regarding the problem - well, that might be the case, I guess...

Comment: Thank you for your response. Regarding my site i get the username and password form clients and some of the details are working for me some time user given details are not correct so that i need to email him again to get user name password. That is why i am thinking How i check the user given details are correct on that form. they are giving me username,password and admin url. with these details there is any way to check that user given details are correct.

Comment: @developerme Yes, there is. But if these sites are remote, then you won't be able to perform these checks with AJAX. You'll have to send given credentials to your server and it will have to connect to given remote site (I suggest using XMLRPC to check if they're correct)